# Synchronous $resource in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, authentication, angularjs, cookies

I'm in a dead end, because I know that Javascript isn't made for synchronous work, and specially not AngularJS. However, I am in a situation where I am stuck needing it.

I have one main page on the domain "www" (with AngularJS), that calls "api" a lot. Some of the resources on "api" requires authentication, so it returns an 401, which in turn AngularJS picks up and displays a login-box when it sees.

The www-login supports a bunch of login methods and sends the password/oauth/whatever to the "api", which returns a token which the angular app stores in a cookie, and sets in `$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization']` so it can be used to authenticate furter requests to the api.

The same method is also used to get the username that belongs to the api-token.

This works perfectly and solves my design goals. But if the browser is going to an url that requires authentication, the 401 (and hence the login box pops-up). This is (I guess) because angular is not able to populate the Authorization field in the header before the 401 hits the browser..

Solutions?

1. Have an async=false request using jquery?
2. Close the login-box when we are done getting the data we want. The login box might flicker...
3. Store more meta-data about the login (ie, username) in cookies, so we dont haveto do get this information from the server when the app is loading.
4. ??

Is there a better solution? This one time, for this one request, I want async=false in my Angular resource....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I went for (which works perfectly) is to set `$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Token ' + old_api_token;`, before the async request. And then overwrite it when the async request is done (if it have changed).